# Installing R in ubuntu

Tags: r, ubuntu, apt-get

I am trying to install R in ubuntu, but faced the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 r-base : Depends: r-base-core (>= 3.0.0-2lucid) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: r-recommended (= 3.0.0-2lucid) but it is not going to be installed
          Recommends: r-base-html but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Before doing this, I also added this line to /etc/apt/sources.list

```
# added from cran.cnr.berkley.edu for R
deb http://cran.cnr.berkeley.edu/bin/linux/ubuntu lucid/
```

But when I tried to update, I received an authentication error:

```
...
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://cran.cnr.berkeley.edu lucid/ Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 51716619E084DAB9
```

Any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: Did you follow the instructions in the [SECURE APT section](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/#section_4)?

Comment: Also the 'W'arning at the bottom has nuttin' to do with the 'E'rror above.  You have an issue with your package depends, plain and simple.  And what that is, we cannot see from what you posted.

Comment: Thanks, now I did the secure APT:

sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E084DAB9

But still when I try installing r-base, I face the exact same problem. How can I find out more information for this problem?

Comment: Did you do an $ sudo apt-get update to refresh the package index for the new repository?

Comment: Yes, I did, but still no success installing r-base!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also did the instructions for SECURE APT, but still I get the following dependency error:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 r-base-dev : Depends: r-base-core (>= 3.0.1-3lucid) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

But then I used a different mirror (by changing /etc/apt/sources.list) it worked:

```
deb http://cran.mtu.edu/bin/linux/ubuntu precise/
```

Comment: When I append deb "http://cran.mtu.edu/bin/linux/ubuntu precise" at the end of the /etc/apt/source.list, I get the following error : "E: Malformed line 59 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list (dist parse)
E: The list of sources could not be read.". The same with trusty (I'm on the 14.04)

Comment: You lack the "/" after precise